# A collection of LaTeX commands with the corresponding symbols in unicode?

Tags: unicode, resources

The best collection of LaTeX symbols which can be copy/pasted I have found so far in my search is [here](https://gist.github.com/LKS90/252ac41bd4a173be35b0), very short. Is there a [comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) in copy/pastable format, where I can copy the latex command like `\Phi` and the unicode symbol like `Φ`? If not, is there a quick way I could generate such a list, or somehow dig into the source of that PDF and isolate it out somehow? You can copy paste from that PDF but it's a pain, is there any way to separate them out and print them automatically like this:

```
\UppercaseOnes = <value>
\UppercaseOnes2 = <value>
...
\lowercaseones = <value>
```

Or perhaps a CSV or something. Trying to use these in another programming language, and am having to copy/paste, cleanup with regexp, by hand. For example, maybe there is a way to dynamically say "print out all latex symbols that don't have any arguments" or something.

Also, copying from that PDF something results in junk, i.e.

```
^ \leftarrowtriangle ⇐\ \Mapsfrom  \shortleftarrow
- \leftrightarroweq ←[ \mapsfrom  \shortrightarrow
] \leftrightarrowtriangle ⇒ \Mapsto  \shortuparrow
\lightning 1 \nnearrow % \ssearrow
⇐=\ \Longmapsfrom 0 \nnwarrow $ \sswarrow
←−[ \longmapsfrom _ \rightarrowtriangle
=⇒ \Longmapsto  \shortdownarro
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [unimath-symbols.pdf](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) document that is part of the unicode-math package may be close to what you're looking for, and copying and pasting from it seems to work fairly well.

There's also the [unicode-math-table.tex](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/blob/master/unicode-math-table.tex) file that's part of the same package that defines the commands for each character code; you could write a quick script that turns that into the kind of document you're looking for. (In fact, I wrote a quick zsh script myself; the output is [here](https://bitbucket.org/frabjous/workspace/snippets/oB5xkX), but I'm not sure it handled accents and diacritical marks correctly, and I'm too lazy to fix it at the moment.) If you're writing a real program you might prefer to have the code points anyway.

But those really only cover math, and not regular text of various languages or other symbols.

Answer (score 6):

I use emacs' [tex-input-method](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TeXInputMethod)

After activating it `Ctrl-X RET Ctrl-\`
You can do

- `ESC-x describe-input-method` which gives you a 300 line file 5 column
  (though the number of columns depends on your screen width).  In any case about 1600 chars. Here's a snippet

  ```
  \.Y Ẏ  \"{I} Ï    \ngtr  ≯    \daleth  ℸ    \blacklozenge        ✦
  \.Z Ż  \"{O} Ö    \nleq  ≰    \degree  °    \construction        
  \.a ȧ  \"{U} Ü    \nmid  ∤    \eqcirc  ≖    \ordmasculine        º
  \.b ḃ  \"{W} Ẅ    \nsim  ≁    \exists  ∃    \risingdotseq        ≓
  \.c ċ  \"{X} Ẍ    \odot  ⊙    \female  ♀    \textcircledP        ℗
  ```
- More pertinently if you sorta-kinda know what you're looking for, you can type a `\` and start fishing around
- Finally there's the larger more comprehensive [math-symbol-lists](https://github.com/vspinu/math-symbol-lists)

### Caveats

1. Not official; not at all complete; not guaranteed consistent with actual (la)tex
2. vi etc probably have similar methods but not sure
3. If you do this in a latex file (buffer in emacs lingo) and you're using pdflatex (not xelatex or luatex) you need to undo it and put the backslash followed by the ASCII by hand after switching off the `tex-input-method`